# Umbraco Content Name

Tags: umbraco, invalid-url

In Umbraco CMS, I would like to prevent the contents to have names having invalid URL character such %, > and etc.

How should I do that?

Regards,

Nami

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your /config/umbracoSettings.config file, it already has a set of replace characters, among which the % character. You can add more if you want to.

If, for any reason you would want to completely prevent those characters in the nodename, you would have to write an afterSave [eventhandler](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/event-examples) so you can do the replace in your own custom code.